# UIImageView with redirected URL doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

I am loading `UIImageView` with a remote URL. It works well for normal URLs. But it doesn't load image if the URL will be redirected. I am using `SDWebImage`.

For example.

[This is image works](http://cp91279.biography.com/1000509261001/1000509261001_1822909398001_BIO-Biography-29-Innovators-Mark-Zuckerberg-115956-SF.jpg)

But

[This image doesn't work](https://manchikatla.co.uk/file-upload/T6uFJxHSrvbiXc2CN/small.jpg)

I didn't find any stackoverflow post regarding this issue.

Comment: Your second image gives a 403

Comment: I am using amazon S3. This URL opens fine in my browser. It is giving 403 in incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue now, it seems to with me amazon s3 CORS Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give you bucket public list permission, which might not be a great idea. See [Amazon S3 Bucket Public Access Considerations](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5050).

Comment: If it's not great idea, how can I use the URL in UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will solve your problem.

```
UIImageView *imgView;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                   action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
[imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


- (void)imageViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourURL];
}
```